# how to finding the duplicates in the map of lists?

Tags: trigger, map, after-trigger

I have a requirement.for that I create a trigger. on that trigger  I am using the Opportunity -Sobject and List of OpportunityContactRoles comes under the opportunity. Now I form the map as followingly

```
if (!(MapName.containsKey(mapkey))) {
    triggerNewMap.put( KEY, new List<OpportunityContactRole>());
}
triggerNewMap.get(mapkey).add(OpportunityContactRolevalue);
```

in this here if I give the input on followingly,

1. mapkey1, OpportunityContactRoleList1
2. mapkey2, OpportunityContactRoleList2
3. mapkey1, OpportunityContactRoleList1

Then how to prevent the last one case?  for any answers thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're setting OpportunityId, ContactId, and Role, you might not need the Map at all. Set considers all fields in the SObject when doing duplicate checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the type of values of your map.
Currently you have:

```
Map<String, List<OpportunityContactRole>> triggerNewMap = new Map<String, List<OpportunityContactRole>>();
```

You have to change it to a Set :

```
Map<String, Set<OpportunityContactRole>> triggerNewMap = new Map<String, Set<OpportunityContactRole>>();
```

The Set class contains a `contains()` method.
You can check if the set already contains the value before adding it.

Comment: Isn't SObject by themself are not hashed properly? I know you can use Set<Id>, but not Set<Account>. I think same apply to Opportunity ContactRole

Comment: @ytiq I'm sorry for the prior comment notification. I had linked the wrong question. I have a [working demo](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71423) of using an SObject as a key in a map. You can also use them in a Set. It's all about how you design your setup; they must contain the same fields and the same values to be a match. I've used this for all kinds of data deduplication, because I don't have to create a custom class just to handle the situation of finding duplicates.