# Strange behavior with Map use

Tags: apex, map

I don't understand the behavior of the map. Here is my case :

```
Map<ContractLineItem, Decimal> cliWithNbrMap = data(otherParameters);
for( ContractLineItem cli : cliWithNbrMap.keySet()){
    system.debug(  cliWithNbrMap.containsKey(cli));
}
```

The Map is not empty, i get the first value And  get false for other values
This is a snippet of my code

```
for(Integer i=1; i<= woNbr ; i++){
            List<ContractLineItem> prestationOfWO = getPrestationsByWONbr(i, prestationsWithWONbr);
            Map<ContractLineItem,Decimal> prestationsOfWOWithVEPoints = new Map<ContractLineItem,Decimal>();
            for(ContractLineItem prestation : prestationOfWO){
                prestationsOfWOWithVEPoints.put(prestation, prestationsWithVEPoints.get(prestation));
            }
            prestationsWithRank.putAll(getPrestationsWithRank(prestationsOfWOWithVEPoints));
        }
```

```
Map<Integer, Decimal> passageNbrWithduree = getDureeListAfterSurBooking (TauxReferenceList,BouclePrestation, getWODuree(prestationsWithRank.get(BouclePrestation),BouclePrestation.CLI_DureeVisite__c),nbrPassages);
```

```
private static Map<ContractLineItem,Integer> getPrestationsWithRank(Map<ContractLineItem,Decimal> prestationsWithPointsVE){
        Map<ContractLineItem,Integer> prestationsWithRank = new Map<ContractLineItem,Integer>();
        Map<Integer,Decimal> rankAndPointsVE = new Map<Integer,Decimal>();
        //get the rank according to points VE
        if (prestationsWithPointsVE.size()>0){
            List<Decimal> sortedPointsVE = sortDescending(prestationsWithPointsVE.values());
            for(Integer i=1 ; i<= sortedPointsVE.size(); i++){
                rankAndPointsVE.put(i,sortedPointsVE[i-1]);
            }
        } 
        for(ContractLineItem prestation : prestationsWithPointsVE.keySet()){
                prestationsWithRank.put(prestation, getRankByPointsVE(prestationsWithPointsVE.get(prestation),rankAndPointsVE));
                System.debug('prestation: ' + getRankByPointsVE(prestationsWithPointsVE.get(prestation),rankAndPointsVE));
        }
        System.debug('prestationsWithRank: ' + prestationsWithRank.size());
        return prestationsWithRank;
    }
```

Comment: Well the map is empty. And you should avoid ever using any `SObject` as a map key. Use its Id instead.

Comment: As per Salesforce documentation Map keys can be of SObject type as well please find the documentation from Salesforce "Map keys and values can be of any data type—primitive types, collections, sObjects, user-defined types, and built-in Apex types."

Comment: As my parents often said, and as I eventually learned, just because you *can* do something doesn't mean that you *should*.

Comment: Is this snippet the _exact_ code that you're running? If it is, then I cannot reproduce what you're seeing. Given that the map is empty, `keySet()` should return an empty list, which means that the `system.debug();` is never executed. Also, there are some applications where using SObjects as a map key are appropriate, but this doesn't look to be one of them.

Comment: @AdrianLarson the map is not empty it contains data.

Comment: This is not a code snippet i just showing how i debogue it

Comment: Just because it *can* be a map key does not mean it *should* be, or that you will use it properly. Using them makes mistakes extremely easy to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify an sObject after it is placed in the key, its `hashCode()` value changes, and the value will become "lost" in the map. There are some hacks to fix this, but you should not rely on such hacks.

## Invalid

```
Map<ContractLineItem, Decimal> cliWithNbrMap = new Map<ContractLineItem, Decimal>();
ContractLineItem key = new ContractLineItem();
cliWithNbpMap.put(key, 1);
// We are altering the hashCode
key.Quantity = 2;
for( ContractLineItem cli : cliWithNbrMap.keySet()){
  system.debug(  cliWithNbrMap.containsKey(cli)); // key not found
}
```

## Valid

```
Map<ContractLineItem, Decimal> cliWithNbrMap = new Map<ContractLineItem, Decimal>();
ContractLineItem key = new ContractLineItem();
key.Quantity = 2;
cliWithNbpMap.put(key, 1);
// We did not change the hashCode
for( ContractLineItem cli : cliWithNbrMap.keySet()){
  system.debug(  cliWithNbrMap.containsKey(cli)); // Key is found
}
```

Notably, this behavior is expected if you do something like:

```
Map<ContractLineItem, Decimal> cliWithNbrMap = new Map<ContractLineItem, Decimal>();
ContractLineItem key = new ContractLineItem(...);
cliWithNbpMap.put(key, 1);
// We modified the record's Id field...
insert key;
for( ContractLineItem cli : cliWithNbrMap.keySet()){
  system.debug(  cliWithNbrMap.containsKey(cli)); // Key not found
}
```

Because the act of doing an insert changes the Id field, which in turn changes the object's `hashCode()`.

In cases like this, it may be prudent to instead use two lists:

```
ContractLineItem[] items = new ContractLineItem[0];
Decimal[] values = new Decimal[0];
// populate both lists at once
insert items;
for(Integer index = 0, size = items.size(); index < size; index++) {
  ContractLineItem item = items[index];
  Decimal value = values[index];
}
```

Comment: In my case the sObject (key) doesn't change this is why i putted it in key side

Comment: @MAH You haven't provided enough information in your question to provide any other solution. If you have a bug on your hands, we would need to see more precise code. As far as I'm aware, the only scenario that can cause this is by messing with the keys after placing them in the map.

Comment: i edited my post to show my code

Comment: @MAH I'm guessing your problem is in getPrestationsWithRank. Oh, also, I forgot to mention in my previous comment, but changing your debug log level can affect the output of the containsKey method. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/254891/2984

Comment: the method getPrestationsWithRank does the job well. I have the expected values. Thank you for this article, I will delete all my sysdebug