# Merging two accounts if they have the same website,EIn and phone number

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I am working on a batch class to merge two accounts if they have the same website,EIn and phone number.
I did a code and tested with accounts having same EIN same phone number and same website and it is getting merged but when I add the same EIN different phone numbers and website then also it gets merged.
(NB:I have given condition only for the EIN).

Code:

```
global class deDuplicateRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    
    public String queryString;
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        queryString = 'SELECT EIN__c,phone,website FROM Account WHERE EIN__c != null';
        // system.debug(queryString);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(queryString);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> acc) {
        
        Map<String,List<Account>> AccountMap = new Map<String,List<Account>>();
        Set<String> Ein = new Set<String>();
        Set<String> Phone=new Set<String>();
        Set<String> Website=new Set<String>();
        for(Account a :acc){
            if(a.Ein__c!= null)
            {
                Ein.add(a.Ein__c);
                
            }
        }
        String sobjectApiName = 'Account';
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(SobjectApiName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        List<String> fieleList = new List<String>();
         List<Account> mergeList;
        for(String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet()){
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
            if(!fieldResult.isCalculated() && fieldResult.isCreateable() && !fieldResult.isExternalId() ){
                fieleList.add(fieldName);
            }
        }
        
        String fetchFields = 'SELECT '+String.join(fieleList,',')+' FROM '+sobjectApiName+' WHERE EIN__c IN :Ein ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC ';
        integer i = 1;
        for(Account a : Database.query(fetchFields)){
            String key = a.Ein__c;
            key = key.toLowerCase();
            System.debug('key'+key);
            if(AccountMap.containsKey(key)){
                AccountMap.get(key).add(a);
            }else {
                AccountMap.put(key,new List<Account>{a});
            }
            i++;
        }
       
        
        for(String key : AccountMap.keySet()){

            if(AccountMap.get(key).size()>1 && AccountMap.get(key).size() <4){
                mergeList = new List<Account>();
                Account masterAcc = AccountMap.get(key)[0];
                mergeList.addAll(AccountMap.get(key));
                mergeList.remove(0);
                
                for(Account a : mergeList){
                    Database.MergeResult mergeResult = Database.merge(masterAcc, a, true);
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        
    }
}
```

Here I have given only the EIn as key now but earlier I tried concatinating with the website and phone number and tried that way but it isnt merging then also. Also is this the ideal way because I feel there are some limiations this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did a code and tested with accounts having same EIN same phone number and same website and it is getting merged but when I add the same EIN different phone numbers and website then also it gets merged.

That's exactly what your code specifies to do:

```
        for(Account a : Database.query(fetchFields)){
            String key = a.Ein__c;
            key = key.toLowerCase();
            System.debug('key'+key);
            if(AccountMap.containsKey(key)){
                AccountMap.get(key).add(a);
            }else {
                AccountMap.put(key,new List<Account>{a});
               
            i++;
        }
```

You identify merge candidates by `Ein__c` only. If you wish to locate records by multiple criteria here, you'll need a *composite key*. [Here's](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71423/what-is-a-use-case-where-one-would-use-an-sobject-as-a-map-key/71436#71436) an example from the inimitable sfdcfox of how to use sObject instances to do that. (Note that you'll have to, as in the linked example, *construct* sObject instances, since your queried data contains other fields than the ones you need to use as keys).

Comment: I understood the concept but how do I apply this in my case?