# CPU Time limit exception inside trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, class, governorlimits

Facing issue while running the trigger , However unable to find the issue as code is moreover optimised and using map already. Logic is on the basis of field A and B find related record in another object and if present sum the new record with latest number else create a new record.

The time consumption majorly it shows inside update statement , when I run and analysed using log analyser.

```
trigger Trigger ABAggregate on ABPayout (after insert,after update,after delete) {
    Map<String,Set<String>> resultMapMPAT = new Map<String,Set<String>>();
    Set<String> MPAT = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> MPATMember = new Set<String>();
    
    for(ABPayout processRecord : Trigger.new){
        System.debug('Trigger size : '+Trigger.new.size());
        if(processRecord.Keypat__C!=null ){
            Set<String> MPATAggregate = new Set<String>();
            if(resultMapMPAT.get(processRecord.Keypat__C)!=null){
                MPATAggregate= resultMapMPAT.get(processRecord.Keypat__C);
                MPATAggregate.add(processRecord.MemberId); 
            }else{
                MPATAggregate.add(processRecord.MemberId);  
                resultMapMPAT.put(processRecord.Keypat__C, MPATAggregate); 
            }
        }
    }    
    
    Map<string,parentAggPay__C> mpatmemberagrregate = new Map<string,parentAggPay__C>();
    List<parentAggPay__C> aggregateToCreate = new List<parentAggPay__C>();
    List<parentAggPay__C> aggregateToUpdate = new List<parentAggPay__C>();

    List<parentAggPay__C> aggregateList = [select id,PMMember__c,Keypat__C,VLdiscount__c from parentAggPay__C where Keypat__C in:resultMapMPAT.keyset()];
    if(aggregateList.size()>0){
    for(parentAggPay__C agg : aggregateList){
        String rebateProgramMPATId=String.valueOf(agg.Keypat__C).substring(0, 15);
        String memberId=String.valueOf(agg.PMMember__c).substring(0, 15);
        mpatmemberagrregate.put(rebateProgramMPATId+'-'+memberId,agg);
    }    
    }    
    System.debug('mpatmemberagrregate : '+mpatmemberagrregate);
    
    For(ABPayout mp:trigger.new){
        if(mp.Keypat__C!=null){
            String rebateProgramMPATId=String.valueOf(mp.Keypat__C).substring(0, 15);
            String memberId=String.valueOf(mp.MemberId).substring(0, 15);
            parentAggPay__C aggregate = mpatmemberagrregate.get(rebateProgramMPATId+'-'+memberId);
            if(aggregate!=null){
                Decimal oldAmount = Trigger.oldMap.get(mp.Id).TotalRebateAmount;
                aggregate.VLdiscount__c = (aggregate.VLdiscount__c - oldAmount)+ mp.TotalRebateAmount;
                aggregateToUpdate.add(aggregate);
            }else{
                aggregate = new parentAggPay__C();
                aggregate.PMMember__c = mp.memberId;
                aggregate.Keypat__C = mp.Keypat__C;
                aggregate.VLdiscount__c = mp.totalrebateamount;
                aggregateToCreate.add(aggregate);
            }
        }
    }
    
    System.debug('aggregateToCreate : '+aggregateToCreate);
    System.debug('aggregateToUpdate : '+aggregateToUpdate);
    
    if(aggregateToCreate.size()>0){
        insert aggregateToCreate;
    }if(aggregateToUpdate.size()>0){
        map<id,parentAggPay__C> mapAggUpd = new map<id,parentAggPay__C>();
        mapAggUpd.putall(aggregateToUpdate);
        update mapAggUpd.values();
    }
    System.debug('aggregateToCreate : '+aggregateToCreate);
    System.debug('aggregateToUpdate : '+aggregateToUpdate);
    
}
```

Comment: is this the only logic running on those objects? No other triggers, workflow, record-trigger flow, etc?

Comment: No , these are the only objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of logic bugs in it. resultMapMPAT should be a plain old Set, Trigger.new can't be used in an after delete trigger, you should never truncate 18-character ID values like that (it's only by a happy accident that your code works with 15-character ID values here), and the code is overall inefficient. However, none of that actually means to say that this code could possibly cause a CPU limit to occur. I find it unlikely that this trigger can, itself, cause a CPU timeout, unless you have many, many records to deal with. That said, we can heavily optimize this to fix all the problems and likely eliminate the CPU limit exception.

```
trigger ABAggregate on ABPayout (after insert,after update,after delete,after undelete) {
    Set<String> keypatIds = new Set<String>();
    // Insert and update
    if(Trigger.new != null) {
        for(ABPayout processRecord: Trigger.new) {
            keypatIds.add(processRecord.Keypat__c);
        }
    }
    // Update and delete
    if(Trigger.old != null) {
        for(ABPayout processRecord: Trigger.old) {
            keypatIds.add(processRecord.Keypat__c);
        }
    }
    // Remove null value
    keypatIds.remove(null);

    Map<parentAggPay__C,parentAggPay__C> mpatmemberagrregate = new Map<parentAggPay__C,parentAggPay__C>();
    List<parentAggPay__C> updatedAggregates = new List<parentAggPay__C>();

    // Existing records
    for(parentAggPay__C agg : [select PMMember__c, Keypat__c from parentAggPay__c where Keypat__C in :keypatIds]){
        mpatmemberagrregate.put(new parentAggPay__C(Keypat__C=agg.Keypat__C, PMMember__c=agg.PMMember__c),agg);
    }
    // Newly calculated values
    for(AggregateResult result: [
            SELECT Keypat__c keypat, MemberId memberId, SUM(TotalRebateAmount) totalRebateAmount
            FROM ABPayout
            WHERE Keypat__c = :keypatIds
            GROUP BY Keypat__c, MemberId
        ]) {
        parentAggPay__C key = new parentAggPay__C(Keypat__C=mp.Keypat__C, PMMember__c=mp.MemberId);
        parentAggPay__C aggregate = mpatmemberagrregate.remove(key);
        // Record doesn't exist.
        if(aggregate == null) {
            updatedAggregates.add(new parentAggPay__C(
                    PMMember__c = (Id)result.get('memberId'),
                    Keypat__C = (Id)result.get('keypat'),
                    VLdiscount__c = (Decimal)result.get('totalRebateAmount')
                )
            );
        } else {
            // Update the total value
            aggregate.VLdiscount__c = (Decimal)result.get('totalRebateAmount');
            updatedAggregates.add(aggregate);
        }
    }
    // Place new records next to others for DML to be efficient
    updatedAggregates.sort();
    // Insert or update records
    upsert updatedAggregates parentAggPay__c.Id;
    // Delete records that had no totals.
    delete mpatmemberagrregate.values();
}
```

Of course, I took some liberties in this code, I can't guarantee everything is correct, but this is the general algorithm for doing this kind of summation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion will go over the Also , And try to implement and optimize . Just a question what does mp refers here         parentAggPay__C key = new parentAggPay__C(Keypat__C=mp.Keypat__C, PMMember__c=mp.MemberId);

Comment: @Marvel See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/71423/2984) where I explain it a bit more. We create a composite key to find the matching record efficiently.